# How do I convert logic to set theory

Tags: logic

In mathematical logic we have certain operators like $\to$, $∨$, $⇔$, ~, ^ etc. How can I convert these operators to the ones used in Set Theory.

I know a few, for example $∨$ is like $∪$, ~ is like $'$ (complement), ^ is like $∩$ .

But how do I convert $\to$, $⇔$ and others to set Theory?

I need this because it is really helpful to solve logic questions as Set theory questions becuase truth tables take a lot of time and it is helpful for a exam that I'm preparing for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will $A\subseteq B$ and $A=B,$ respectively, do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be very careful in "converting" operators, it does not always work as students think it does.

But in principle, $A\Rightarrow B$ is nothing but $(\neg A) \lor B$, and $A\Leftrightarrow B$ is $(A\land B)\lor (\neg A \land \neg B)$.